# Don't allow values ​other than the one defined to be added. MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document, called QuestionSchema, which has a field called "standardAnswer", I would like to have the possibility to let this field receive only the values that I have allowed it to receive.

For example, it would be "positive", "negative"...

Is there any option in the Schema creation or anything that I could do to achieve that?

Comment: use mongodb enums, if you want to solve the validation problem in general in your code you can use class-validator to validate your input before doing any multi step operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for enums/schema validation.
Try this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 0):

No, MongoDb does not support `tuples`. Many types are supported, the most common ones being:

- Double
- String
- Object
- Array
- Binary data
- Boolean
- Date
- Null
- Regular Expression

You will have to create a method or function which would only allow db operations in the cases you set.